# BIOS reports usable memory 8MB less than installed

Tags: memory, bios, memtest86+

I have 7168MB total of DDR3 RAM, in one stick of 1024MB and three of 2048MB.

It seems that regardless of my memory configuration (I tried different sticks on their own), BIOS always states that there is 8 megabytes less than expected of usable memory; what's more, in the full 7GB configuration, Memtest86+, despite completing one pass (I didn't do more) with no errors, seems to be testing only 7159MB (but that extra megabyte is probably occupied by Memtest itself).

What could be the possible reason? I'm trying to abstract this question from a specific hardware configuration, but the specifications might help, so here they are: the motherboard is ASUS P7H55 with support for dual channel memory and there are - as stated above - four sticks of DDR3 1333MHz (timings 9-9-9) memory manufactured by Hynix.

I ran Memtest86+ on another PC (an old one with DDR1 RAM) and only 1 megabyte was unusable (likely the one occupied by Memtest).

What would be the possible cause for 8 to 9 megabytes of memory being unavailable, when the memory itself seems to be working fine?

Comment: Install and test each stick individually, see if one shows smaller than it should be.

Comment: @Moab it seems that my system always reports 8MB less of memory than there should be, regardless of how many and which sticks I put in there. See updated question.

Comment: Then it is using the missing memory for something hardware related

Comment: Often this is assigned to the shared graphic memory. I saw this often on Intel mobos where you could select the amount of shared graphic memory from 1 to 128 MBs. Check in your BIOS if you can find a setting like this. If not, it definitely should be a hardware reservation as @Moab suggested (the question is just if you will be able to identify it somehow).